# How to get a three-view-drawing in threejs?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I'm developing a edu production for kids.

I want to get three view drawing for most geometry model.

I've tried EdgesGeometry, the problem is that sphere geometry is not good enough, and any geometry with smooth face is quite no good ToT.

[Good For EdgesGeometry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vKaK.png).
[Not good for edgesGeometry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgIDI.png).
Do you know any way to draw a three view drawing?

Help me plz...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially [`How do I ask a good question?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [`How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Regarding your question, a sphere naturally doesn't have edges. Instead, what you want are sometimes called "silhouette edges." This involves rendering the shape in a way that only a thin strip is visible, rendered in a different color.